# Porting Perl string substitution to Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, string-substitution

I'm trying to figure out how to do string substitutions while in the process of porting a Perl script to Ruby.

Here's the Perl line. I'm trying to figure out Ruby's equivalent:

```
$historyURL =~ s/COMPONENT_NAME/$componentName/g;
```

For those of you who may know Ruby, but not Perl, this line basically substitutes the string "COMPONENT_NAME" in the `$historyVariable` with the value of the `$componentName` variable.

Comment: I'm curious why this question was downvoted, it seems like a perfectly legitimate question to me, one that I wasn't able to resolve by myself looking at Ruby's API (due to my lack of experience with regular expressions in general)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equivalent is pretty straight-forward:

```
history_url.gsub!(/COMPONENT_NAME/, component_name)
```

The `gsub!` method replaces *all* instances of the given pattern with the second argument and stores the result in the original variable as it is an in-place modifier. `gsub` by comparison returns a modified copy.

Comment: The `=~` operator exists in Ruby but cannot be used to make modifications as in Perl. It's generally not used, though, in favor of using `match` or the various `sub` methods for reasons of clarity.

Answer (score 0):

The nice thing about the `gsub`-method is that it does not need a regex, it works fine with a string (or a variable pointing to a string):

```
history_url = "some random text COMPONENT_NAME random text COMPONENT_NAME"
component_name = "lemonade"
p history_url.gsub("COMPONENT_NAME", component_name) # no regex
#=> "some random text lemonade random text lemonade"
```